# How to keep the range on an interactive plotly coloraxis constant through different frames?

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating an interactive map of pedestrian data that varies over time, so that a slider controls the time on a particular day and the count of pedestrian is shown as a 'densitymapbox' type plotly plot. However the range on the coloraxis keeps changing as the time is also changing. how can i have this stay constant and the scale to remain contanst through the different frames?

code:

```
fig <- DATA4
fig <- fig %>%
 plot_ly(
   type = 'densitymapbox',
   lat = ~latitude,
   lon = ~longitude,
   z = ~DATA4$Hourly_Counts,
   hoverinfo = 'z',
   coloraxis = 'coloraxis',
   frame = ~DATA4$Time,
   radius = 30,
   opacity = 0.75,
   zmax = 6000,
   zmin =0
 
   ) 
fig <- fig %>%
 layout(
   mapbox = list(
     style="carto-positron",
     center= list(lon=144)), coloraxis = list(colorscale = "Viridis"))

fig
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

coloraxis.cmax or zmax must have particular value.
You can find highest and put it into cmax.

If cmax have 0 (default) - it will update automaticallyю

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).